# Matlab list of all past warnings in current session

Tags: matlab

Is there a way to get a list of all the warnings that have been issued during a Matlab session?

E.g. if I do:

```
warning('hello world');
```

I can retrieve this warning by the [function](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/lastwarn.html):

```
lastwarn
```

However, how do I store/retrieve ALL past warnings? E.g.

```
warning('hello world 1');
warning('hello world 2');
warning('hello world 3');
```

Comment: The only way I can think of is to use `diary`.

Comment: That would be perfect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you can use the function [diary](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diary.html) which stores your command line output.